# Access HttpServletRequest in OData4j service provider

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, odata, odata4j

I realise that this is pretty much a duplicate of [How to access HttpServletRequest in Odata service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675608/how-to-access-httpservletrequest-in-odata-service-provider), but since it didn't get any anwser I'll try my chances.

The concensus for this problem seems to be "use @Context HttpServletRequest req to inject it" by I have no idea how I should do this, since I am not familiar with this concept at all.

I am using a jersey servlet container. Here's my web.xml

```
<servlet>
<description>Servlet container</description>
<display-name>Default</display-name>
<servlet-name>Default</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <description></description>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.odata4j.producer.resources.ODataResourceConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <description></description>
  <param-name>odata4j.producerfactory</param-name>
  <param-value>mypackage.MySqlProducerFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
```

How should I approach this?

Thanks a lot!